# Magento 2 : How to get Select Options in Template from Attribute Source Model

Tags: magento2, customer, template, customer-account, select

I created a custom attribute for customer entity, with options from another db_table

**I want to display this field as a select item (with options from source model) in the registration page (customer_account_create)**

I created all the needed files but i don't know how to get the options (created in source model) in the template file

Here is all the created/needed files:

**InstallData** Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);



        $setup->startSetup();

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'testfield', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Test Field',
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true, 
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'source' => 'Vendor\Module\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Test'
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'testfield')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','checkout_register'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();

        }
    }
```

**Source Model** Vendor/Module/Model/Customer/Attribute/Source/Test.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source;


class Test extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $helper = $obj->create('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data');
        $tags = $helper->getCollection();
        foreach($tags as $tag){
            $label = $tag->getName();
            $value = $tag->getCode();
            $option[] = array('label'=>$label,'value'=>$value);
        }
        $this->_options = $option;

        return $this->_options;
    }

}
```

**Helper** Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_tagsCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test\CollectionFactory $tagsCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_tagsCollectionFactory = $tagsCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_tagsCollectionFactory->create();
        return $collection;
    }

}
```

**Layout** Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional_info_customer" template="Vendor_Module::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**Template (Needed file)** Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/additionalinfocustomer.phtml

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>

   <!-- Need select item for testField customer attribute -->
   <!-- Options from db_table (in source model)-->
   ............................................................


</fieldset>
```

Could any one help me how to get this select options in template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config as EavConfig;

protected $eavConfig;


public function __construct(
    ...
    Config $eavConfig
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    ....
}
```

Now you can load your attribute like this,

```
$yourAttribute=$this->eavConfig->getAttribute('customer','YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE');

if($yourAttribute->getSource()){
    $options = $yourAttribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
}
```

---

Using `ObjectManager` (Not recommended)

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$yourAttribute = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Config')->getAttribute('customer','YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE');

if($yourAttribute->getSource()){
    $options = $yourAttribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
}
```